# Linking JavaFX files - FXMLController file, FXML file, Java code

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm fairly new to JavaFX, and I'm building a GUI game. I coded the logic of the game before in Java, and now I'm trying to integrate it with SceneBuilder. This doubt may be very basic and obvious, but I can't seem to understand where I'm going wrong.

I have to create a timer label on my SceneBuilder canvas, that pulls the time from the java code and updates that on the GUI. This timer isn't a regular timer, which is why I can't just use a clock in my controller. I *have* to use the value I get from the Java code. 
Here it is:

**FXML Controller file:**

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    public SampleController getSampleController(){
        return this;
    }

@FXML private Label displayTime;

@FXML
public void updatePage(String data){
    displayTime.setText(data);
}

@FXML
private void handleStartGameA1(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException{
System.out.println("Game has been started!");
World w = new World();
w.runGame();
}
```

**FXML file:**

```
  <Label id="displayTime" fx:id="displayTime" layoutX="381.0" layoutY="125.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="301.0">
     <font>
         <Font size="18.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
```

**Java file:**

```
public class World {
    public static Clock WorldClock; // Clock class only to get the custom time

    public World(){
        WorldClock = new Clock();
        public void runGame() throws InterruptedException{
        for (int minute=0; minute<=WorldProperty.MaxMinutes/10; minute++){

        // irrelevant code

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        SampleController sc = new SampleController();
        sc.getSampleController();
        sc.updatePage(WorldClock.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

**The Runtime Error:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafxapplication1.SampleController.updatePage(SampleController.java:41)
    at World.World.runGame(World.java:102)
    at javafxapplication1.SampleController.handleStartGameA1(SampleController.java:52)
    ... 55 more
```

What could be going wrong? I feel I'm being unconventional by creating a SampleController constructor, but I've gathered that it works from online resources. Also, in the `updatePage(String data)` function, if I don't update the label and simply print a statement `System.out.println("The time is: " + data);`, it works perfectly well. 
This leads me to believe that for some reason the label is not getting updated correctly. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You don't load the FXML, so the UI components, including the label, don't get created, and you don't connect the controller to the FXML loader.

You need something like

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
SampleController sc = new SampleController();
fxmlLoader.setController(sc);
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("path/to/file.fxml"));
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
// display root somewhere...
```

Comment: My issue is, the Java file I'm putting this code in, does not have any root/scene/stage. Those components have been declared in yet another java document using `public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {`. Do I necessarily need to have a stage in this Java document too? I'm using 2 java documents because as I said, I wrote the code earlier so it's not been integrated with JavaFX.

Comment: Well, no. Presumably you are actually already loading the FXML file *and displaying its contents* somewhere. You need to get the reference to the controller when you do that. Else you just have a reference to another instance of the controller class (in which, as you have discovered, the `@FXML`-annotated fields are not initialized).

Comment: Right, I understand. Could you elaborate more on how to get a reference to the controller, rather than get a reference to an instance of the controller?

Comment: Just do exactly what I posted at the point in the code where you load and display the FXML file. Then `sc` will be a reference to the actual controller that is controlling the displayed UI (not a reference to another instance of the same class, which is what you have in your code).